# css float images side by side in this crop

Tags: css

I have a crop function in CSS to do square images in css. It gets the image and create a square.
It is doing it well. My problem is, one image is over the other one and I can't float them side by side. Any ideas?

**CSS**

```
.ccontent {
  float:left !important;
  display:inline-block !important;
}

.c{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.c img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.c img.portrait {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

The tree image is over the sea one:

See [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hy1d6az6/)

Comment: Your structure is very odd - the image are overlapping because they are children of the same parent, they are not separate cuts. Very odd.

Comment: oh, thank you for your answer! any suggestion to make it better? @somethinghere

Comment: I added my answer below. I also suggest using more descriptive classes. It sounds like a great idea to use `c` as it produces short code, but come back to it in a year and you will confuse yourself over which class did what and why. Consider using good descriptions like `crop` and `content`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

html:

```
<div class='c'>
  <img src='https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/09/fa/82/57/img-20160107-wa0006-largejpg.jpg' alt='name1' class=portrait>
</div>

<div class='c'>
  <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Grewia_tiliaefolia_tree_in_Chilkur,_Hyderabad_W_IMG_9418.jpg' alt='name1' class=portrait>
</div>

</div>
```

Css:

```
.c{
 position: relative;
 float:left;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.c img{
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.c img.portrait {
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z0370m0o/

Answer (score 4):

You need to think in separate chunks. The strange thing about your code is how it is structured. You only need two things: a wrapper (positioned relative) and an image (positioned absolute).

```css
.crop {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.crop img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.side-by-side { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class="crop side-by-side">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" /> 
</div>
<div class="crop side-by-side">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/340x340" /> 
</div>
```

Now with this, you can easily consider the wrapper your block and display it as an `inline-block` or position it absolute if you need to, but you have two very separate units that can be copied anywhere and will always share the same behaviour (cropping the image). At this point, you have basically defined a block that crops an image - after that, just treat it like any other element in CSS (just don't adjust its overflow and don't give it a `static` position.

By the way, I use the `side-by-side` class to illustrate that you should keep the cropping behaviour separate from any other stylistic choices, so you can easily combine them into a working element without any fuss.

As an addition, here's a little thing I usually do to make sure the image spans my entire crop area:

```
img { min-width: 100%; min-height:100 %; }
```

Comment: @Jay thank you, but my answer had addressed that 'issue'. The main issue here is thinking in discrete blocks, after that you can treat the block like any other element by adding displays, floats, etc...

Comment: Ah, I see now. Apologies (Y)